# Leaflet : add layerGroup to specific pane

Tags: leaflet, pane

This below code doesn't seem to work, as every layer contained in my fournituresLayer groupLayer still have 'overlay pane' as reference.

```
let map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    attributionControl: false,
    dragging: true,
    keyboard: true,
}).setView([0, 0], 20);

map.createPane('fournituresPan')
map.getPane('fournituresPan').style.zIndex = 450;
map.getPane('fournituresPan').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

let buildingLayer = L.layerGroup([])
let fournituresLayer = L.layerGroup([], { pane : 'fournituresPan'})
let electricityLayer = L.layerGroup([])
```

Do anybody know how to add a layerGroup to a specific Pane ?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the PaneName with option 'pane' when you add your LayerGroup to the map

```
    L.layerGroup([], { pane: 'markerPane' }).addTo(this.map)
```